# Why does mathematica not display the graph?

Tags: differential-equations, graphics

I want to substitute the solution of a differential equation into a function, and  plot the function.
My code is as attached:

```
teta=NDSolveValue[{θ''[t] == (m l (g -i (θ'[t])^2 Cos[θ[t]]) (Sin[θ[t]] - μk Cos[θ[t]]))/(i +m l^2 Sin[θ[t]](Sin[θ[t]] - μk Cos[θ[t]]))
, θ[0] == π/2, θ'[0] == 0} /. {m -> 0.03517,l -> 0.0279,g -> 9.81,i -> 10.^-3 ,μk -> 0.1827}, θ , {t, 0, 5}]

F[t] =={ m l (θ''[t] Cos[θ[t]] - θ[t]'^2 Sin[θ[t]])} /. θ[t] -> teta//Simplify
```

The code works until here. When I try to plot `F[t]`, mathematica only displays the axes but not the graph itself. Please send help. Thank you.

Comment: In `F[t]`, `l`, `m` and  `(\[Theta]^\[Prime]\[Prime])[t]` are undefined. Also, `F[t] = ...` not `F[t] == ...`.

Comment: If i use F[t]= instead, would I be able to plot the graph?

Comment: Also need to define `l`, `m`, and `θ''[t]` in the definition of `F`.

Comment: Why do I have to define θ''[t]?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

teta = NDSolve[{θ''[t] == (m l (g - 
            i (θ'[t])^2 Cos[θ[t]]) (Sin[θ[t]] - μk Cos[θ[t]]))/(i + 
          m l^2 Sin[θ[t]] (Sin[θ[t]] - μk Cos[θ[t]])), θ[0] == π/
        2, θ'[0] == 0} /. {m -> 0.03517, l -> 0.0279, 
      g -> 9.81, i -> 10^-3, μk -> 0.1827}, θ, {t, 0, 5}][[1]];

F[t_] := m l (θ''[t] Cos[θ[t]] - θ'[t]^2 Sin[θ[
         t]]) /. {m -> 0.03517, l -> 0.0279} /. teta

Plot[F[t], {t, 0, 5}]
```

[image]